# How to enter nvarchar data type in varcher datatype column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `tb1` and `tb2`. `tb1` has a column `c1` of datatype `varchar(15)` and `tb2` which is created from an Excel file using import/export in SQL Server has a column `c2` of datatype `nvarchar(255)`. All data is numeric with digits ranging from 5 to 12. I want to update the data in `c1` with the values in `c2`, but while updating through a query I am getting an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

How can I  update data of `c1` with the values of `c2`?

Comment: One option could be for you to edit the Excel column (c2) using TRIM and then try the import/export from column (c1). That should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The values in c2 probably have trailing spaces. Use the trim function to remove the spaces.
 Your update should be something like:

```
update tb1
set c1 = LTRIM(rtrim(tb2.c2))
from tb1
join tb2 on tb1.id=tb2.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Your field is not big enough to hold your data.
you cant put something that can be 255 characters long into something that`s 15 characters long.

You need to increase (c1) to at least varchar(255)